# How to initialize scoped dependencies for consumers using MassTransit filters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, masstransit

I would like to initialize some dependencies resolved from the MassTransit serviceProvider in the same way Asp.Net Core does with the pipeline's middlewares.

In particular I would like to inspect the incoming message before the consumer is called and extract the tenant from it (I'm currently working on a multitenant web application with single database per tenant).

With this informations I need to initialize some scoped instances (Ef Core DbContext for example).

I know that I can inject them in the Consumer through constructor but this means that I must do that everytime I write a new one, so I suppose that a filter should be the right place (correct me if I'm wrong).

The problem raises when I need to access the current consumer scope to resolve the dependencies that I need. I was thinking that the behavior of the MassTransit' pipeline was similar to the Asp.Net one regarding middleware injection but I was probably wrong.

I haven't found any documentation on how to do that clearly without cluttering the code of the filter, so any suggestion is going to be really appreciated.

This is the filter that I need to modify:

```
public class TenantContextInitializerFilter<T> : IFilter<T> where T : class, ConsumeContext
{
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context) { }

    public async Task Send(T context, IPipe<T> next)
    {
        //Resolve scoped instance here and do something before Consumer is called
        var connectionStringProvider =  scope.GetService<IConnectionStringProvider>();

        await next.Send(context);
    }
}


public class RegistrationsDeliveredEventConsumer : IConsumer<IRegistrationsDelivered>
{
    private readonly IConnectionStringProvider _connectionStringProvider;

    public RegistrationsDeliveredEventConsumer(IConnectionStringProvider connectionStringProvider)
    {
        //This should be the same instance that has been resolved in the filter' Send() method
        _connectionStringProvider = connectionStringProvider;
    }

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IRegistrationsDelivered> context)
    {

    }
}
```

This is a simplified example of my code but this should be enough

Comment: _I must do that everytime I write a new one_: Not sure I follow this. If your consumer has a dependency, it is much better to have it specified explicitly in the constructor of the consumer class instead of hiding it.

Comment: Why not inject a factory delegate that will construct and init the appropriate dependencies dependant upon a key you specify for each combination?

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev In the consumer implementation I have only one dependency which is the Mediator object (https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR). This helps me hiding all the complexity from the Consumer class

Comment: @TraeMoore Can you provide an example of that?

Comment: @BrandoCaserotti the essence of MediatR is to do some kind of in-proc messaging. MassTransit does the same but it's distributed. So, I am wondering why it is at all needed? I'd say you need an application service that you call from the consumer, that's all. If you still want MediatR, it's just one interface and it's quite easy to take it as an explicit dependency still. Plus, no one said that you need to have one class per message type. You can have one class consuming different messages.

Comment: @AlexeyZimarev What you say is correct, but the Consumer should trigger a well known usecase that is part of the domain and that can be triggered buy a user from the user interface also. So I am reusing Mediatr to avoid code duplication.

Comment: @BrandoCaserotti - sure, I can provide an example. Is `IRegistrationsDelivered` a custom interface or something from MassTransit?

Comment: @TraeMoore yes is a custom interface for a simple event. I don't know where to store the tenantId yet (maybe in the message header?). Imagine a situation like that

Comment: @BrandoCaserotti - How/where are you creating the `IConnectionStringProvider`?

Comment: It is registered in the serviceCollection in the startup class (serviceCollection.AddScoped<IConnectionStringProvider>). Basically it holds the connectionstring of the current tenant through a basic setter

Comment: I'm having the same issue, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There's two facets to consider: 1) are filters registered as services/pulled from the service collection when using the ASP.NET Core integration and 2) what lifetime do the filters have if they are. I'm not familiar with the MassTransit ASP.NET Core integration, but it *looks* like you should be good based on a cursory review. You'll need to confirm that both of those requirements are met.

For dependency injection, in general, constructor injection is the way to go unless there's a very specific need to do something different, which does not seem to be the case here. In short, you need a constructor for your filter.

What exactly you need to inject is a function of the lifetime of the filter. If it has a transient lifetime, then you can inject your scoped dependencies directly. If it has a singleton lifetime, then you'll need to inject `IServiceProvider` instead, and do the following whenever you need to use one of those dependencies:

```
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var dep = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyDependency>();
    // do something with `dep`
}
```

Comment: I've already tried injecting a ServiceScopeFactory but the problem is that the scope is not the same from which MassTransit creates the Consumer (which is scoped also) and every dependency that is needed. I should be able to access the same scope without creating a new one to acomplish my issue.

Comment: Anyway the filter has a singleton lifetime

Comment: Why would you think it should be. That's the entire point of a scope. The dependencies you pull out in the scope only exist within that scope. Since the filter is a Singleton, then yes, you will have to wrap every operation involving one or more dependencies with a scope.

Comment: I've edited my question. If you need further details just ask me, I would be glad to provide them. Thank you for your time btw.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a draft... I'm sure there are missing pieces, so let me know if you have questions.

```
public class TenantContextInitializerFilter<T> : IFilter<T> where T : class, ConsumeContext
{
    private readonly Func<string, IDbConnection> _dbContextAccessor;
    public void Probe(ProbeContext context) { }

    public TenantContextInitializerFilter(Func<string, IDbConnection> dbContextAccessor)
    {
        _dbContextAccessor = dbContextAccessor;
    }

    public async Task Send(T context, IPipe<T> next)
    {
        var tenantId = ""; // place holder
        using (var dbContext = _dbContextAccessor(tenantId))
        {
            //... do db logic
        }

        await next.Send(context);
    }
}

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IConnectionStringProvider>(
            provider => null /* TODO figure out how to fetch scoped instance from a cache or some storage mechanism*/);

        services.AddScoped(provider =>
        {
            IDbConnection Accessor(string tenantId)
            {
                if (provider.GetService<IConnectionStringProvider>()
                    .TryGetConnectionString(tenantId, out var connectionString, out var providerName))
                    return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                throw new Exception();
            }

            return (Func<string, IDbConnection>)Accessor;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code @Trae Moore but I don't think this is going to solve my problem. I'm sure MassTransit creates its own scope for every incoming message,  within which consumer is resolved (and all his scoped constructor dependencies). I need the same instance of IConnectionString in the filter class (and I don't know how to do that) and in the Consumer class (is ofc a simplified example but this is the key concept)

Comment: Someone has already had the same issue [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55957555/getting-masstransit-to-use-scoped-lifetime) (read the comments)